# Validating product # against another list

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have two lists. Validating product # against another list In the infopath form. When users put product #, it needs to be checked if it exists in the other list before allowing submission.

I prefer to do it in drop down because of the amount of data in another list. I used eval fn and it worked fine for some time, but when the data increased, in the other list the form failed to start. Need help

Comment: Can you provide more specific error details? When you say "data increased",  approximately what figure of total items that means?

Comment: @Muhammad . Thanks for your respond my list item is more than 5000 item . That is why I said data increased more and more, So It doesn't loop. If you have any other option please let me know . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your problem correctly, you are trying to fetch all product numbers from the list and populating it in a drop down in infopath form.

If there are more than **5000** items in the list and you are trying to retrieve all of them at once, then it will be a problem as SharePoint has a limitation of threshold value which is by default set to 5000 items. You can change this value but then there will be a lock on the table in SQL Server and no other operation can be performed at that time.

I think populating all of the items at once is not the best idea here. I would suggest you here to create few more dropdowns in infopath forms and categories your data. Rather than loading all items in one dropdown, first load main categories in first dropdown and than its sub categories in second dropdown and then load the product numbers in third dropdown which you have currently.

You have to do something on your data organization level if its really the threshold issue. Or change the way you are retrieving data in InfoPath form by categorizing it.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks again Muhammad Appreciated!! The drop down should be hidden, that's why I need some way to know the values (count) in drop down without looking at it so that I can write validation rule. Need help please

Comment: If you need only values (count) , you don't need to populate them in drop down first and then count. You can get that using CAML query and get the list items count directly from SharePoint. See here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26150/is-it-possible-to-return-only-the-count-of-the-query